# CMake generate Xcode project :ld: library not found for -lQuadProgpp

Tags: xcode, build, cmake

My CMake project works well independently in terminal. However, when I use CMake generate Xcode project. I cannot build the project.

It says:

> ld: library not found for -lQuadProgpp clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Who can tell me what the problem is? And how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: More info please: How this library is linked in your `CMakeLists.txt`, where is this library located actually. Add this informaton into your question post via [edit].

Comment: I have no experience with Xcode, but from experience with other IDE's my suggstion is that the environment variables differ from the teminal. So check your environment in the terminal and compare them with the ones in Xcode (if possible).